# Haskell: Couldn't match type when using ImplicitParams with Rank2Types

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use `ImplicitParams` together with `Rank2Types` in order to build a custom Monad for my application. However, I get the error below, which I don't understand.

Here is a complete example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types                 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}

import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Random hiding (random)
import Control.Monad.Random.Class

data Hint = Hint { good :: Int
                 , bad  :: Int }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

class Combination c where
  random   :: Env c
  fromList :: [Int] -> Env c
  toList   :: c -> Env [Int]  

class Combination c => Set s c where
  empty     :: (?combination :: c) => s
  fromList' :: [c] -> s
  member    :: c -> s -> Bool
  insert    :: c -> s -> s

  notMember :: c -> s -> Bool
  notMember c s = not (member c s)

type Env' a = Rand StdGen a

newtype Env a = Env { unenv :: forall i1 i2 c s .
                      Integral i1
                      => Integral i2
                      => Combination c
                      => Set s c
                      => (?colors :: Int)
                      => (?holes  :: Int)
                      => (?hint   :: c -> c -> Env Hint)
                      => (?combination :: c)
                      => (?set    :: s)
                      => (?cardinality :: i1)
                      => (?powers :: [i2])
                      => Env' a }

instance Functor Env where
  fmap f (Env a) = Env $ fmap f a

instance Applicative Env where
  pure = Env . pure
  (Env f) <*> (Env a) = Env $ f <*> a

instance Monad Env where
  (Env m) >>= f = Env $ m >>= \a -> let (Env b) = f a in b

instance MonadRandom Env where
  getRandomR  = Env . getRandomR
  getRandom   = Env getRandom
  getRandomRs = Env . getRandomRs
  getRandoms  = Env getRandoms



-- Dummy instances
instance Combination Int where
  random = undefined
  fromList _ = undefined
  toList _ = undefined

instance Set Float Int where
  empty = undefined
  fromList' = undefined
  member = undefined
  insert = undefined


-- Tests
f :: forall c i.
     Combination c
  => Integral i
  => (?colors :: Int)
  => (?cardinality :: i)
  => (?combination :: c)
  => (?hint :: c -> c -> Env Hint)
  => c -> Env String
f _ = do
  r <- getRandomR (100::Int, 200)
  secret <- random :: Env c
  r1 <- random :: Env c
  h <- (?hint secret r1)
  return $
    show ?colors
    ++ " " ++ (show $ fromIntegral ?cardinality)
    ++ " " ++ show r

g :: forall c.
     Combination c
  => (?combination :: c)
  => Env String
g = do
  r <- random :: Env c
  Env $ unenv $ f r
  --            ^^^
  --            ERROR: Couldn't match type ‘c1’ with ‘c’...
```

I tried almost everything to make it work without any success, here is the error message :

```
Internal.hs:92:17: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘c1’ with ‘c’
        arising from a functional dependency between constraints:
          ‘?combination::c’ arising from a use of ‘f’ at Internal.hs:92:17-19
          ‘?combination::c1’
            arising from a type expected by the context:
                           forall i1 i2 c s.
                           (Integral i1, Integral i2, Combination c, Set s c, ?colors::Int,
                            ?holes::Int, ?hint::c -> c -> Env Hint, ?combination::c, ?set::s,
                            ?cardinality::i1, ?powers::[i2]) =>
                           Env' a0
            at Internal.hs:92:3-19
      ‘c1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall i1 i2 c1 s.
          (Integral i1, Integral i2, Combination c1, Set s c1, ?colors::Int,
           ?holes::Int, ?hint::c1 -> c1 -> Env Hint, ?combination::c1,
           ?set::s, ?cardinality::i1, ?powers::[i2]) =>
          Env' String
        at Internal.hs:92:3-19
      ‘c’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          g :: forall c. (Combination c, ?combination::c) => Env String
        at Internal.hs:(86,1)-(89,15)
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘f r’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘unenv $ f r’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: Env $ unenv $ f r
    • Relevant bindings include r :: c (bound at Internal.hs:91:3)
   |
92 |   Env $ unenv $ f r
   |                 ^^^
```

The point is that I don't want to add every implicit parameter to the signature of every single function in my program in case I want to add other parameters in the future.

Thanks.

EDIT: I just discovered `PartialTypeSignatures` which could solve my problem in a much simpler way, I'm trying this out now!

Comment: Complete **minimal** example? Really? Also, what is the error message?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Sorry I tried to make a smaller example but I couldn't reproduce the same error (I'm quite a Haskell newbie, and those extensions are totally new for me). I edited my question to add the full error message.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
Env $ unenv $ f r
```

you should simply use

```
f r
```

Doing `Env $ unenv $ ...` introduces a new bunch of rigid type variables `i1 i2 c  s`, which have to be matched by `unenv $ ...` and GHC meets some ambiguity here, I guess. There should be some way to force `unenv $ ...` to use the exact same rigid variables, but it's not worth it, since we can avoid that.

Further, to call `f r` you also have to define the other implicit arguments like `?cardinality, ?colors, ?hint`. Otherwise, you'll still get an error.

Comment: Thank you but I would like to avoid defining every implicit arguments in the signature of every function in case I want to add other parameters in the future, hence the `Env $ unenv $ ...` trick to (hopefully) bring them all into scope. I would be interested in a way to force `unenv $ ...` to use the same rigid variables.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I came up with a solution using `PartialTypeSignatures`. I could have avoided signatures altogether, but in some cases I need to bring in some constraints. The only downside is that I still need to define full signatures on type class methods, but I can live with it. Here is an example :

```
{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams        #-}

class SomeClass a where
  method :: Real t => (?var1 :: t) => IO a

instance SomeClass Int where
  method = return $ floor $ realToFrac $ ?var1 + 1

instance SomeClass Float where
  method = return $ realToFrac $ ?var1 + 1

someFun :: _ => SomeClass a => a -> IO a
someFun x = do
  v <- method
  return $ v + ?var2

f :: forall t. _ => SomeClass t => (?proxy :: t) => IO t
f = (method :: IO t) >>= ?fun

g :: _ => Num t => IO t
g = do
  v <- f
  return $ v + 1

v1 :: IO Int
v1 =
  let
    ?var1 = 10
    ?var2 = 20
    ?proxy = undefined :: Int
  in let
    ?fun = someFun
  in g

v2 :: IO Float
v2 =
  let
    ?var1 = 10.1
    ?var2 = 20.2
    ?proxy = undefined :: Float
  in let
    ?fun = someFun
  in g

main :: IO ()
main = do
  r1 <- v1
  r2 <- v2
  print r1
  print r2
```

I'm still open to suggestions though :) .

Side note: One downside of implicit parameters is that you must bring them into scope as soon as you want to reference a function or a value with implicit parameters constraints. As a consequence you cannot compose those functions without bringing *all* their parameters into scope. A potential solution to this problem is explained in [this blog post](http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/07/delaying-implicit-parameter-binding/).

Comment: Well, I would suggest you at least consider using some more conventional style. Implicit parameters are a longtime oddball in the Haskell language. I don't say they're bad – frankly I don't know, because hardly anybody uses them, including myself. But there definitely are good alternatives.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I was using a simple reader monad until I needed polymorphic values. Then I tried to use a type class (with a reader monad), but it couldn't be used with proxies... I don't know any alternatives for that particular use case, probably because I'm still a beginner.